Mathematical explanation about "he average performance over the $k$ folds gives us a lower bound on the generalization of the model to unseen data"
I read in a book that: the average performance over the $k$ folds gives us a lower bound on the generalization of the model to unseen data. I am looking for the mathematical explanation of this sentence.

Let's start with some notation.
We'll assume your dataset is $\{X, Y \}$, where the $X$ are your data points and the $Y$ are some categorical labels. This whole thing works for regression problems as well, but we'll just do the classification-problem case. For simplicity let $Y$=$\{0,1\}$.
We'll also assume that your $X$ ~ $\mathfrak{D}$ are i.i.d.
When you train your model, you learn some function $f(x)$ and the error with respect to that function is some loss-function, usually some kind of metric, i.e. $\hat{e}_f(x) = |\hat{y}-y|$, with $f(x)=\hat{y}$. So $\hat{y}$ is some kind of guess your model has made of what $f$ looks like at $x$. The mean of all these guesses over your full dataset $X$ is called the empirical risk. Now the true error, or the true risk is given by:
$$\mathbb{E}_{x \sim \mathfrak{D}} [\hat{e}_f(x)]$$.
Now, a basic result from statistical learning theory (very roughly stated here) is that the more data you have, the more your empirical risk is going to approximate your true risk. The reason for this is larger datasets will sample the true data distribution much better (a dual, and drawback of this is that, everything else being the same, your generalization performance will suffer; this is also a function of the model complexity, but let's not go down that rabbit hole).
The result itself is kind of intuitive. As as an example, consider flipping a coin one time or ten times. In the first case, you will have to estimate the probability of heads $p$ as 1 if the coin comes up heads, and 0 otherwise. If you flip ten times, you will get those estimates only in the event that all coins come up heads or all coins come up tails, which has probability $\frac{1}{2^9}$. This is just because in the 10-flip case you have more insight into what $p$ is, simply because you have sampled better
We can apply this to the machine learning case. In the end, the problem is that your trying to estimate a function, i.e. a joint distribution of samples and their associated labels, from a set of "point" examples, much like you were trying to guess the true value of $p$ from a sequence of coin flips. For the coin case we can state the following inequality relating the $n-th$ moments of the empirical risk.
$$\mathbb{E}[e_{p_{10}}^m] < [e_{p_{1}}^m]$$
For the $k$-fold case in which you are interested, the relationship is basically the same. Your moments are upper-bounded by the average of the moments of your $k$ individual folds. Formally, let $e_k^T$ be the the true risk on your $k$-th fold, i.e. on the dataset where the $k$-th set is treated as a hold-out. On each of the folds we learn a possibly slight different function $f_k$. The true risk and empirical risk are given respectively as
$$e^T_{\mathbf{K}} = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k e_k^T$$ (true risk)
and
$$\hat{e_{\mathbf{K}}}=\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=0}^k \hat{e}_k$$ (empirical risk)
Then we have, similar to the coin flips above,
$$\mathbb{E}[|e^T_{\mathbf{K}}-\hat{e}_{\mathbf{K}}|^m] \leq \mathbb{E}[|e^T_i-\hat{e}_i|^m]$$
for any single fold $i$, which you can show using Jensen's inequality (beware, this requires convex error-funcs, but most conventional error-funcs are convex, so no problem!). The bound can be sharpened to a true inequality under certain. conditions. In particular, by picking $m=1$ you get your desired result. The $k$-th fold acts as a hold-out on each of the runs.
Now, when you apply the model to unseen data two kinds of things can happen. In the bad case, you will encounter training examples that lie way outside the distribution of the training samples you saw during training. So $X$ actually only captured some of the true support of $\mathfrak{D}$. The other bad thing would be if the functional relationship is different. For example suppose you are trying to learn the absolute value function, but all the $x's$ you saw during training were from $\mathbb{R^+}$. Then the training data is is consistent with the true functional relationship being the identity.
In both cases, you'll be screwed and your generalization error will obviously outgrow your $k$=fold estimate.
The good case is when your unseen data follow the same distribution as your $X$. So you've sampled pretty nicely cool. However, in that case you can return to the above case, since the error on your unseen data will behave exactly as the error on each $one$ of the folds.
